# Вывод данных из БД в ListView

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь реализовать вывод данных из БД по нажатию на кнопку в ListView, но ничего не происходит. Ошибки никакой не выдает. Пытался сделать по примеру http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/278-urok-136-cursorloader.html.

Вот что получилось класс MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText in;
    ListView list;
    SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;

    TestDBHeler db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = new TestDBHeler(this);
        try {
            db.createDataBase();
            db.openDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }

        in = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.in);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        db.close();
    }

    public void search() {
        String string = in.getText().toString().trim();
        String query = "SELECT " + Entry.COLUMN_COL2 + " FROM " + Entry.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Entry.COLUMN_COL1 + " = " + "\"" + string + "\"";

        Cursor cursor = db.database.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (!string.equals("")) {
            try {
                if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        int col2ColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(Entry.COLUMN_COL2);
                        String col2 = cursor.getString(col2ColumnIndex);
                        String[] from = new String[] {col2};
                        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.itemTxt};
                        scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0);
                        list.setAdapter(scAdapter);
                    }
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onClickBtnSearch(View view) {
        search();
    }
}
```

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="18sp">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/in"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:height="46dp"
                    android:hint="Введите слово"
                    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/stat_notify_sync"
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                    android:onClick="onClickBtnSearch"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                    android:layout_weight="0.28" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/list" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Класс TestDBHeler где используется готовая БД

```
public class TestDBHeler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/test.testdb/databases/";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "databaza.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    private Context myContext;

    public TestDBHeler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
        }else{
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch(SQLiteException e){
        }
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(database != null)
            database.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}
```

Что я упустил?

P.S. пытался реализовать интерфейс LoaderCallbacks как в примере по ссылке, но тоже ничего не получилось

Comment: У вас многие блоки `try...catch` без вывода ошибок. Возможно ошибка как раз на моменте создания\открытия БД? А также на момент самого выбора данных? Добавьте вывод стека во все `SQLiteException`

Comment: В этих местах ошибок нет. Потому что в обычный textview все прекрасно выводится. Решил заменить вывод в textview на listview но ничего не выводится. Может я что-то упустил

Comment: `String[] from = new String[] {Entry.COLUMN_COL2};`

Comment: Все равно не выводится. Кстати везде проставил вывод стек-трейса как советовали. Никаких ошибок не показывает.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    int col2ColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(Entry.COLUMN_COL2);
    String col2 = cursor.getString(col2ColumnIndex);
    String[] from = new String[] {col2};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.itemTxt};
    scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0);
    list.setAdapter(scAdapter);
}
```

В этом блоке вы в цикле постоянно создаете новый адаптер и сетите его для ListView и в массив from нужно передавать название колонки

```
String[] from = new String[] {Entry.COLUMN_COL2};
```

Вынесите создание адаптера, массивов и setAdapter в onCreate, и без цикла доставайте курсор с вызывайте метод

```
scAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);
```

Куда будете передавать курсор с данными из БД

Comment: Вынес 

String[] from = new String[] {Entry.COLUMN_COL2};
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.itemTxt};
scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0);
list.setAdapter(scAdapter);

в метод onCreate. в методе search() осталось
if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
                    scAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);
                }

Но у меня выкинуло исключение в строке scAdapter.changeCursor(cursor); что поле _id не существует. В БД оно существует. Почему этот метод использует _id? как вообще действует этот метод? Вот в курсор вывели все что нашли и что делает метод?

Comment: @kolhoz используй adapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder(){public boolean setViewValue(View aView, Cursor aCursor, int aColumnIndex) {if(aColumnIndex == (тут индекс твоей колонки 2){TextView textView = (TextView) aView;
                textView.setText})}}